# why does my function execute twice in my loop?

Tags: python

When i execute my code below, it makes me repeat the process of entering the input *twice* , anyways to fix that?

```
def hi():
    while True:
        try:
            a=int(input("enter the denominator of Pi radian\n"
            "(choose from 1,2,3,4,6)\n"
            "Enter here:"))
            if a<=0 or a>=7 or a==5:
                print("Enter the given digits")
                hi()                       
            else:
                return a                         
        except Exception:
            print("enter a valid type")                  
ant=hi()
print(ant)
```

Comment: In your own words, what *exactly* do you think happens when you call `hi` from within `hi`?

Comment: Because you call it again inside your function after print

Answer (score 1):

What you are missing is the `return` on the `hi()` call within your `hi` function.

```
def hi():
    while True:
        try:
            a=int(input("enter the denominator of Pi radian\n"
            "(choose from 1,2,3,4,6)\n"
            "Enter here:"))
            if a<=0 or a>=7 or a==5:
                print("Enter the given digits")
                # just return from here..
                # if you dont, the value you get from `hi` call is not returned
                # and the while loop executes the code one more time
                return hi()                       
            else:
                return a                         
        except Exception:
            print("enter a valid type")                  
ant=hi()
print(ant)
```